# Ebay search API "findItemsAdvanced" method does not return results for multiple listingType

Tags: search, ebay-api, listings

I am using "findItemsAdvanced" method for searching.I stuck into a weird thing that I am trying to fetch cars having listingType :

```
1.FixedPrice
2. StoreInventory
3. AuctionWithBIN
4. Classified
```

But unfortunately I am not getting results for "Classfied" listings I always get "FixedPrice" lisings only not "Classified","AuctionWithBin" etc.

Below is the call which I am trying:

[API CALL](http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?OPERATION-NAME=findItemsAdvanced&SERVICE-VERSION=1.0.0&SECURITY-APPNAME=APP-ID&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=XML&REST-PAYLOAD&GLOBAL-ID=EBAY-US&categoryId=6001&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=20&sellingStatus.sellingState=Active&descriptionSearch=true&itemFilter(0).name=ListingType&itemFilter(0).value(0)=FixedPrice&itemFilter(0).value(1)=StoreInventory&itemFilter(0).value(2)=AuctionWithBIN&itemFilter(0).value(3)=Classified&sortOrder=PricePlusShippingLowest&outputSelector(0)=PictureURLLarge&outputSelector(1)=AspectHistogram&aspectFilter(0).aspectName=Make&aspectFilter(0).aspectValueName(0)=Chevrolet&aspectFilter(1).aspectName=Model%20Year&aspectFilter(1).aspectValueName(0)=2000&aspectFilter(1).aspectValueName(1)=2001&aspectFilter(1).aspectValueName(2)=2002&aspectFilter(1).aspectValueName(3)=2003&aspectFilter(1).aspectValueName(4)=2004&aspectFilter(1).aspectValueName(5)=2005&aspectFilter(1).aspectValueName(6)=2006&aspectFilter(1).aspectValueName(7)=2007&aspectFilter(1).aspectValueName(8)=2008&aspectFilter(1).aspectValueName(9)=2009&aspectFilter(1).aspectValueName(10)=2010&aspectFilter(2).aspectName=Model&aspectFilter(2).aspectValueName(0)=Aveo)

Please help me...

TIA